# docker 1.7.0 under ubuntu14.04,can not run a container,error message "device or resourcebusy "

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

As the title,I can not run a docker container under ubuntu system
like that:

`root@GPU-video:/var/lib/docker# docker run -it ubuntu:14.04 
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 097adf55270348f22a4af715aeb3ce655778dabf2d52773ecfa3bb1172f5eb2b: device or resource busy`

Some stackoveflow question tell me it is device-mapper error,but docker in ubuntu is not use device-mapper,under /var/lib/docker I can not find the dir "devicemapper" or something like that.

When I check the syslog,I find some infomation about the error,like these:

`Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500695.727142] aufs au_opts_parse:1133:docker[29133]: unknown option dirperm1
Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500695.911141] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth5511b43: link is not ready
Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500695.918761] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth5511b43: link becomes ready
Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500695.919189] device veth5511b43 entered promiscuous mode
Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500695.919296] docker0: port 1(veth5511b43) entered forwarding state
Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500695.919313] docker0: port 1(veth5511b43) entered forwarding state
Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500695.974006] docker0: port 1(veth5511b43) entered disabled state
Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500696.004100] device veth5511b43 left promiscuous mode
Jul  9 10:48:49 GPU-video kernel: [500696.004108] docker0: port 1(veth5511b43) entered disabled state`

There seems like something about network interface,so I have down the network interface "docker0" then I restart it,but it did not work,I still get the error.
I have try to restart docker ,unstall then install docker,but they all can not fix the error.
Who can help me?

Comment: I have this same error when my ubuntu machine is booting up `aufs au_opts_parse:1133:docker[29133]: unknown option dirperm1`. More here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371509/aufs-au-opts-parse1155docker2010-unknown-option-dirperm1