# aufs au_opts_parse:1155:docker[2010] unknown option dirperm1

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I installed Docker. Now, when my Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty system tries to boot, I get the following message

```
aufs au_opts_parse:1155:docker[2010] unknown option dirperm1
```

What does this mean, and how can I get my system back to a stable stage to where I can start it up normally. If this would help: I have a container that is set to `--restart on-failure` and that is set to access H/W devices.I also have minikube installed, which had a VirtualBox-based Docker engine running in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#known-issues-run
- https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/783#issuecomment-123705753

Upgrading to docker 1.9.1 solved it.

Comment: How can you upgrade when the system is not booting? I have the same problem. My system is only able to boot with an old kernel into recovery mode